# My main container is not covering the entire page while using flexbox and sitting to the left even when i try to center

Tags: html, css

I want the entire container to be horizontally centered, but what i discovered was that before even doing that, its sitting on left and not covering the whole page. What am i doing wrong? Am I not setting the width of page properly? or am i using flexbox wrong?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*or 1 em*/
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Twitch Tv Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitchcss.css">

  <!--jquery link-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!--main container-->

    <div class='mainCont'>
      <!--heading container-->
      <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
    </div>
    <!--end of heading container-->

    <div class='onlineContainer'>
      <div id="imgFirst"></div>
      <div id="textSecond"></div>
    </div>
    <!--end of online container-->

    <div class='offlineContainer'>
      <div id="imgFirst1"></div>
      <div id="textSecond1"></div>
    </div>
    <!--end of offline container-->
  </div>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Twitch Tv Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitchcss.css">

    <!--jquery link-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!--main container-->

      <div class='mainCont'>
        <!--heading container-->
        <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
      </div>
      <!--end of heading container-->

      <div class='onlineContainer'>
        <div id="imgFirst"></div>
        <div id="textSecond"></div>
      </div>
      <!--end of online container-->

      <div class='offlineContainer'>
        <div id="imgFirst1"></div>
        <div id="textSecond1"></div>
      </div>
      <!--end of offline container-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="twitchjs.js"></script>

  </body>

  </html>

</body>

</html>
```

I want the entire container to be horizontally centered, but what i discovered was that before even doing that, its sitting on left and not covering the whole page. What am i doing wrong? Am I not setting the width of page properly? or am i using flexbox wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the width of `body` to `100vh` to `100vw` or `100%` as `vh` is equal to 1% of viewport height and `vw` is equal to 1% of viewport width. Then add `width: 100%` to `.container`. Check the snippet for better understanding.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  /*or 1 em*/
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Twitch Tv Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitchcss.css">

    <!--jquery link-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!--main container-->

      <div class='mainCont'>
        <!--heading container-->
        <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
      </div>
      <!--end of heading container-->

      <div class='onlineContainer'>
        <div id="imgFirst"></div>
        <div id="textSecond">Second</div>
      </div>
      <!--end of online container-->

      <div class='offlineContainer'>
        <div id="imgFirst1"></div>
        <div id="textSecond1">Third</div>
      </div>
      <!--end of offline container-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="twitchjs.js"></script>

  </body>

  </html>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to set a `width` on the body here. You are using `divs`, which are block level elements and will take up 100% width by default.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--main container-->

  <div class='mainCont'>
    <!--heading container-->
    <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
  </div>
  <!--end of heading container-->

  <div class='onlineContainer'>
    <div id="imgFirst"></div>
    <div id="textSecond"></div>
  </div>
  <!--end of online container-->

  <div class='offlineContainer'>
    <div id="imgFirst1"></div>
    <div id="textSecond1"></div>
  </div>
  <!--end of offline container-->
</div>
```

Comment: could you clarify why you did html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

Comment: You can read about it here: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/